# Telerik ASP.NET AJAX - Ajax Update Label with dynamic created Docks

Tags: ajax, dynamic, telerik, dock

i try to Update a simple Label on Close Event of dynamic created RadDock.
Works fine so far, Label gets the correct values but doesnt updates it.

```
   RadDock dock = new RadDock();
            dock.DockMode = DockMode.Docked;
            dock.UniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            dock.ID = string.Format("RadDock{0}", dock.UniqueName);
            dock.Title = slide.slideName;
            dock.Text = string.Format("Added at {0}", DateTime.Now);
            dock.Width = Unit.Pixel(300);
        dock.AutoPostBack = true;
        dock.CommandsAutoPostBack = true;
        dock.Command += new DockCommandEventHandler(dock_Command);

...

void dock_Command(object sender, DockCommandEventArgs e)
{
Status.Text = "Removed " + ((RadDock)sender).Title + " " + ((RadDock)sender).Text;
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(dock, Status, null);
```

while creating the docks, but on runtime i get a NullReference Excepetion.

On a Button registered with the RadAjaxManager it works to show the value 
assigned by dock_command.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Status.Text = Status.Text;
    }
```

UPDATE: The RadAjaxManager was created with integrated Wizzard of VS2008.
Can't select the Docks, because the are generated while runtime.
On Backend its included in AutoCompletion, so the NullReference has nothing to do
with the AjaxManager itself. Like i said, works fine with the Button.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1">
       <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="Button1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Label1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
```

Comment: Can you post what your RadAjaxManager block looks like? I suspect the problem/solution is/will go in there.

Comment: Added it, but I don't think its the RadAjaxManager block because it was created with VS2008 Wizzard/Config and works fine with a button. But i'm not able to trigger the Ajax Update on that label from the dock_Command Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions was solved by Telerik Support here

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/docking/telerik-asp-net-ajax-ajax-update-label-with-dynamically-created-docks.aspx